# calculating standard deviation in R on a dataframe

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe in R.

```
 index seq change change1 change2 change3 change4 change5 change6 
    1      1   0.12  0.34     1.2     1.7     4.5     2.5    3.4
    2      2   1.12  2.54     1.1     0.56    0.87    2.6    3.2
    3      3   1.86  3.23     1.6     0.23    3.4    0.75    11.2
    ...   ...  ...   ...      ...     ...     ...    ...     ...
```

The name of the dataframe is just `FUllData`. I can access each column of the `FullData` using the code:

```
FullData[2] for 'change'
FullData[3] for 'change1' 
FullData[4] for 'change3'
...
...
```

Now, I wish to calculate the standard deviation of values in first row of first four columns and so on for all the columns

```
standarddeviation = sd ( 0.12  0.34     1.2     1.7 )
then 
standarddeviation = sd ( 0.34     1.2     1.7   4.5 )
```

Above has to be for all rows. so basically I want to calulate sd row wise and the data is stored sort of column wise is it possible to do this. 
How can I access the row of the data frame with using a for loop on index or seq variable ?
    How can I do this in R ? is there any better way ?

Comment: You can access rows with `apply`. Take a look at `apply(data[....], 1, sd)`

Comment: Did you consider transforming data frame from this wide format to long format? Then, you can do a rolling standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this.

```
st.dev=numeric()
for(i in 1:dim(FUllData)[1])
{
   for(j in 1:dim(FUllData)[2])
   {
      st.dev=cbind(st.dev,sd(FUllData[i:dim(FUllData)[1],j:dim(FUllData)[2]]))
   }
}
```

Comment: dim(FullData) is null